# Bootstrap - reduce size of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having two navbars on my page, where in the first one ( `.tob-bar` ) I show my social media and in the second one I have the navigation menu

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse no-margin top-bar">
        <div class="container">

            // social media here ...

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->


<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse no-margin">
        <div class="container">

            // nav menu here ...

        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav><!-- /.navbar -->
```

How can I set the height of the `.top-bar` to lower px? I have tried
to set

```
.top-bar {
   height: 20px!important;
}
```

but doesn't seems to work, it still has the default from bootstrap. I have also tried to check in firebug for any height values, but no luck

Comment: Would you mind quickly making this into a jsFiddle and including bootstrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have also tried to check in firebug for any height values, but no luck

That's because Bootstrap uses `min-height: 50px;` for `.navbar`. The `min-height` property always overrides both `height` and `max-height`. You need to declare your `.top-bar` value as follows:

```
.top-bar {
  min-height: 20px !important;
}
```

Here's an example

```
.top-bar {
  min-height: 60px; /* overrides height and max-height */
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

If height > min-height or vice versa, the value that is the greatest will be the one that is rendered.

Comment: It works but for some reason it seems the menu navbar changes too.. its kinda weird because I have applied `.top-bar` only on the first nav

Comment: Nevermind, fixed it! The margins and paddings from `<li>` elements where messing it up